# Finite Taylor expansion of composition of analytical functions

Tags: complex-analysis

It is known that if $f$ is a complex function that has no poles inside the disk of some positive radius $R$ then one can approximate $f(z)$ for $z$ such that, say $|z| \leq R/2$ using a truncated Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $z=0$ to arbitrary precision.  My question is - whether or not the same thing can be said "up to composition with a holomorphic function"

Formally stated:
Let $R$ be some positive real, $z_0,z_1\in C, |z_0 - z_1| \leq R$ and let $f$ be a complex valued function defined by 
$f = \sum_{i=1}^n ln(1 - z/z_i)$ (not all $z_i$'s need to be unique) and $\gamma: C \to C$ be some
holomorphic function such that the composition $h = f \circ \gamma$ 
satisfies
$$
\forall z, |z-z_0| \leq 2R , \ \ h(z) \neq 0
$$
Then $h(z)$ is analytical at $z=z_0$, and $h(z_1)$ can be approximated to arbitrary precision by a finite Taylor series around $z_0$, up to an integer multiple of $2\pi i$.